# CPU profiler results for groovy application full of reflection calls

Tags: java, groovy, profiling, visualvm

I'm using VisualVM to perform profiling for a Groovy web application, and the stack traces are full of reflection calls that have bloated the trace and made it difficult to read. Is there a way to filter these out? Either at compile time, run time or at view time?

[image]

Comment: I'll note that using Groovy in `@CompileStatic` mode, if available, will eliminate most of these calls.

Comment: thanks, we'll check if we can use that flag, seems to have a lot of impact though

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the results. Just use context menu in VisualVM results.

[image: VisualVM results]